Why is the ssl_session_id being regenerated for some requests and reused for others in nginx?
I have containerized and deployed my angular app to nginx. I want to send a Content-Security-Policy header with a nonce. I am using $ssl_session_id for the nonce from nginx.
I am able to pass the nonce to the angular app and use it. But the issue I noticed is that for the  ssl_session_id of each of the subrequests within the index.html, some are using a seperate $ssl_session_id and some are using the same $ssl_session_id as index.html
Thus the nonce set in the meta tag of the index.html is not matching with the nonce in the Content-Security-Policy header of some subrequests.
The expectation is that the nonce must be regenerated only everytime the index.html is served i.e everytime the angular app is reloaded and not for every subrequest within the index.html.
Below is the index.html.
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  
  <title>CsrfInAngular</title>
  <base href="/">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <meta name="CSP_NONCE" content="NGINX_CSP_NONCE" />
  <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">
  <style >
    h4{
      color:red;
    }
  </style>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="assets/js/external.js"></script>
  
</head>
<body>
  <script>
    console.log("I am an inline script")
  </script>
  <app-root></app-root>
</body>
</html>

Below is the app.module.ts
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { Meta } from '@angular/platform-browser';

  function setCSPNonce(metaService:Meta):()=> InjectionToken<string>{
    return ()=> new InjectionToken(metaService.getTag("name='CSP_NONCE'")?.content || "");
  }

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    HttpClientModule,  
  ],
  providers: [
    {
      provide:CSP_NONCE,
      useFactory:setCSPNonce,
      deps:[Meta],
      multi:true
    }
   
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule {
 }

Below is the nginx.conf I am using right now
server{
    listen 0.0.0.0:5443 ssl;
    server_name innocent.csrfexample.com;
    ssl_certificate     /etc/nginx/secureAngularExample.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/secureAngularExample.key;
    default_type application/octet-stream;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log debug;

set $cspNonce $ssl_session_id;
sub_filter_once off;
sub_filter_types *;
sub_filter NGINX_CSP_NONCE $cspNonce;

    gzip                    on;
    gzip_comp_level         6;
    gzip_vary               on;
    gzip_min_length         1000;
    gzip_proxied            any;
    gzip_types              text/plain text/css application/json application/x-javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript;
    gzip_buffers            16 8k;
    client_max_body_size    256M;



    add_header 'Content-Security-Policy' "default-src 'self'; script-src 'self' 'nonce-$cspNonce';   style-src 'self' 'nonce-$cspNonce' always";
   

    root /usr/share/nginx/html;



        location /assets/ {
         #assets within the root
         autoindex on;
        }


        location / {
        # matches any path within the root
        try_files $uri $uri/index.html /index.html =404;

        }

        
        error_page  404              /index.html;


    }



"The expectation is that the nonce must be regenerated only everytime the index.html is served i.e everytime the angular app is reloaded and not for every subrequest within the index.html." - This expectation that ssl_session_id is constant over all requests from the same client is wrong. What standard or other information make you think that the sessions gets created once when index.html is visited and then never change?

@SteffenUllrich My understanding could be wrong. Please advice, what kind of ID I can use from nginx which will be consistent across subrequests within the index.html and the index.html ? I just want this ID to be regenerated everytime the angular app reloads i.e the index.html is re-served.

Most of the blogs I have seen as of now, use the approach I have mentioned but they dont work

I don't think that there is such an id specific for a client. HTTP is a stateless protocol and TLS does not make it stateful. State between requests is only explicitly shared with cookies.

@SteffenUllrich Thank you. In that case how do I make CSP nonces work with angular and nginx ? Any ideas would be helpful.

Why do you need the nonce to be the same over multiple requests in the first place? For use inside a CSP it should be sufficient if the nonce is the same inside the CSP header for a response and for all nonce attributes in the HTML body of the response - but not relevant for following requests.

Yes.But what about the main.js,pollyfills.js,styles.css in the index.html ? These are not inline scripts or styles. If csp header with different nonce is sent I have a csp violation again. The subrequests
I mentioned earlier are the requests for these files.

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

@SteffenUllrich Thank you for your inputs. Using those I am able to debug what went wrong. It was not due to different nonce per request. It was a configuration mistake in angular.
